# Display the error message after the label title

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I had the form using the simple form like this:

```js
<%= f.input :last_name %>
```

When there is validation error on form the validation error message are display after the input text box like this:

```html
<div class="input string required test_last_name field_with_errors"><label class="string required" for="test_last_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Last name</label>
<input class="string required" id="test_last_name" name="test[last_name]" type="text" value="">
<span class="error">can't be blank</span>
</div>
```

I would like to generate html like below to display the message after the label :

```html
<div class="input string required test_last_name field_with_errors"><label class="string required" for="test_last_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Last name</label> <span class="error">can't be blank</span>
<input class="string required" id="test_last_name" name="test[last_name]" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks
Sabbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I am posting here so that it might help somebody.

In the simple for configuartion file just put the error tag before input like this :

```
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }

b.use :label_input
```

And add this css on error class:

```
float:right
```

Thanks

Sabbu

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but try

```
<%= f.input :last_name as: :required %>
```

I put 2 and 2 together that this was a ruby project after the fact.

```html
<div class="input string required test_last_name field_with_errors"> <label class="string required" for="test_last_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Last name</label><span class="error"> can't be blank</span>
<input class="string required" id="test_last_name" name="test[last_name]" type="text" value="">
   
</div>
```

Comment: This syntax is not correct for ruby 4.0 <%= f.input :last_name as: :required %>

Comment: Frankenmint,I get the RuntimeError - No input found for required.

Comment: Did anybody have any idea about how to solve this issue?Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks.